# Add a Task to all 20 packages in SSIS solution

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have an SSIS project with 20 packages. I need to add a SQL Task to the end of each one (connected to the last Task, of course). Is there any way to do this without copy & pasting the SQL Task in each package? For now, this SQL Task will be identical in each package.

Thanks

Comment: Do you write .NET?

Comment: @billinkc yes, I can write .NET but nothing advanced

Answer (score 1):

Super rough approach for fixing one package. Once it's correct, then iterate through the file system and fix 'em all.

This code is cobbled from old samples and some search engine-fu but it 100% untested and might not even compile. But, it does demonstrate the correct approach using the .NET libraries for manipulating the SSIS packages - which I've not done in a *very* long time

```
// Be sure and add the assemblies as reference or this will not work
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ExecuteSQLTask


        // At this point, we're in Main or some callable method
        Package p = null;
        Application app = null;
        app = new Application();
        string pkgName = @"C\src\ssis\SO_75009716.dtsx";
        string outputFile = @"C\src\ssis\SO_75009716.fixed.dtsx";
        p = app.LoadPackage(pkgName, null);

        // Find the Tasks we have in the package
        Executables executables = p.Executables;
        // Assume the last one listed is the right one to attach to
        Executable lastOne = executables[executables.Length-1];

        // Create our Execute SQL Task
        Executable execSql = p.Executables.Add("STOCK:SQLTask");

        // Cribbing from msdn question
        DTS.TaskHost TKHSQLHost = (DTS.TaskHost)execSql ;
        ExecuteSQLTask MySQLTask = TKHSQLHost.InnerObject as ExecuteSQLTask;

        MySQLTask.Name = @"SQL Run Query";
        MySQLTask.Connection = "AdventureWorks";
        MySQLTask.Source = @"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.all_columns;";

        // At this point, we need to attach our new executable to the existing set of tasks
        execSql.AttachTo(lastOne);

        // Cross your fingers and see how we did
        app.SaveToXml(outputFile, p, null);
```

Reference for all the code

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sqlserver-2019
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/adding-tasks-programmatically?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.tasks.executesqltask.executesqltask?view=sqlserver-2019
- Specific call out for adding an Execute SQL Task
  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/03de78f9-df58-450c-8350-1d65d72bb892/execute-sql-task-in-c?forum=sqlintegrationservices

The other approach, the one I'd use is to install BimlExpress and reverse engineer all the packages into Biml. Then it's a simpler matter of adding an Execute sql task there.

But for 20 packages? Copy and paste + drag your precedent constraint connector unless you just want to gain the experience of how SSIS packages are built under the covers.